# Trying to create a new object based on TypeError: Object of type ItemSerializer is not JSON serializable -

Tags: django, django-views

Im trying to get my data from the api and create a new item with it. I am getting an error:]
File "/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.**class**.**name**} '
TypeError: Object of type Item is not JSON serializable

model

```
# Create your models here.
class Item(models.Model):
    """Make scan class"""
  # define fields
  # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    recycleable = models.BooleanField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        # This must return a string
        return f"The item named '{self.name}' is {self.description}. It is {self.recycleable} that it is recycleable."

    def as_dict(self):
        """Returns dictionary version of Item models and stuff"""
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'name': self.name,
            'recycleable': self.recycleable,
            'description': self.description,
            'owner': self.owner,
            'barcode': self.barcode,
        }
```

views

```
class ScanApiDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes=(IsAuthenticated,)
    def get(self, request, slug):
        """Show request"""
        load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
        api_key = os.environ.get("API_KEY")

        # Locate the scan to show
        response = requests.get(f"https://api.barcodelookup.com/v2/products?barcode={slug}&formatted=y&key={api_key}")
        if response:
            print(response, "my response")
            item = response.json()
            for i in range(len(item)):
                descrip =  item['products'][i]['description']
                name = item['products'][i]['product_name']
                barcode = item['products'][i]['barcode_number']
                recycleable = True
                x = re.search("^Material", descrip)
                owner = request.user.id
                data = Item(id, name, recycleable, descrip, owner, barcode)

                print(type(data), "the data")
                json_data = json.dumps(data)
                print(json_data)
                # # Serialize/create item
                item = ItemSerializer(data=json_data)
                # print(item, "item after serializer")
                # # If the item data is valid according to our serializer...
                if item.is_valid():
                    print(item.data)
                    item.save()
            if item:
                return Response({'item': item}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            errors = "No item found"

        return Response(errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializer

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # owner = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'recycleable', 'description', 'owner', 'barcode')
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you are doing some logical error here

```
item = ItemSerializer(data=json_data)
```

Above this code, you already assigned item as some json value but here inside `if` block you have again assign this variable as an serializer and here

```
if item:
    return Response({'item': item}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

According to me, you are thinking item as json value but it is an serialzer instance.

So you can assign `item = ItemSerializer(data=json_data)` as `item_serializer = ItemSerializer(data=json_data)` or any other variable except item.

I think this can solve your problem